# Pandas not sorting datetime columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe as:

```
df:
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|     |   Unnamed: 0 | country                 | league                       | game                                               | home_odds   |   draw_odds |   away_odds |   home_score | away_score   | datetime            |
+=====+==============+=========================+==============================+====================================================+=============+=============+=============+==============+==============+=====================+
|   0 |            0 | Chile                   | Primera Division             | Nublense - A. Italiano                             | 2.25        |        3.33 |        3.11 |            1 | 0            | 2021-06-08 00:30:00 |
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|   1 |            1 | China                   | Jia League                   | Zibo Cuju - Shaanxi Changan                        | 11.54       |        4.39 |        1.31 |          nan | nan          | 2021-06-08 08:00:00 |
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|   2 |            2 | Algeria                 | U21 League                   | Medea U21 - MC Alger U21                           | 2.38        |        3.23 |        2.59 |          nan | nan          | 2021-06-08 09:00:00 |
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|   3 |            3 | Algeria                 | U21 League                   | Skikda U21 - CR Belouizdad U21                     | 9.48        |        4.9  |        1.25 |          nan | nan          | 2021-06-08 09:00:00 |
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|   4 |            4 | China                   | Jia League                   | Zhejiang Professional - Xinjiang Tianshan          | 1.2         |        5.92 |       12.18 |          nan | nan          | 2021-06-08 10:00:00 |
+-----+--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I have defined `datetime` as `datetime`

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

and then tried to sort it

```
df.sort_values(by=['datetime'], ascending=True)
```

However the sorting does not work.

Can anybody help me understand why?

[Please find the entire dataframe here for reference.](https://filebin.net/hcud1eju9bzsd54o)

p.s. I am unable to paste the entire dataframe here because of character constraints.

Comment: You did `df = df.sort_values(by=['datetime'], ascending=True)` and you just only copied the command, or you didn't update the variable with the sorted dataframe that was returned?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: sort_values (by default) returns a _new_ dataframe with the values sorted. So I was confirming that you did something with that sorted copy. Like, for example, update the `df` variable with it.

Comment: Aha! So I have to reference it as `df = df.sort_values(by=['datetime'], ascending=True)` right? Yep. That works! Thats silly of me. Thank you!

Comment: Following up, what is the _new_ dataframe called?

Comment: What do you mean? `sort_values` returns a value. You would use it like any function that returned a value. `new_df = df.sort_values...`, `df = df.sort_values...` `print(df.sort_values...)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the comments you already found your solution. Copying the `df` back into itself after calling `sort_values()` means it's "new" name is the old name.

I'll add this as an answer.

```
df.sort_values(by=['datetime'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Then it should make the sorting in-place, so you don't have to assign it to itself.